# Click reset button followed by click submit button goes to UPDATE call instead of POST call

Tags: angular

After submitting the submit button first time post call success, and second time it goes to Update call. If I click reset button after submit button call also goes to update cal.l Can any one help me on this?

**Component code**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.refreshEmployeeList();
}

resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form)
      form.reset();
    this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
      _id: "",
      name: "",
      position: "",
      office: "",
      salary: null
    }
}

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value._id == "") {
      this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.refreshEmployeeList();
      });
    }
    else {
      this.employeeService.putEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.refreshEmployeeList();
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if (!form.value._id) {` instead of `if (form.value._id == "") {`.
That way you will not check if `_id` is an empty string but whether its value is `falsy`.